# How to query the feeds of a specified video on youtube?

Tags: youtube-data-api

For example, I only need the feeds of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=179M7qYa7Oo, how should I do query?

I need to do this because I want to embed videos to my app, I want to write a tool to query following properties to make sure I can use it:
yt:accesscontrol   media:restriction     media:price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is api to retrieving information about a single video:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoid?v=2